# Do I have to get an operating system?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10, operating-systems, computer-building

I am interested in building a new PC from scratch for the first time.
I have prepared:
 a CPU, CPU Cooler, Motherboard, RAM,
 an SSD & HDD, a graphics card, case,
 a PSU, monitor, keyboard, mouse and speaker.
**Do I have to get a separate Windows 7/8/10 Operating System if I build a computer from scratch, or are operating systems preinstalled in one of the listed components?**

Comment: Yes, you'll need to get an OS as well as the hardware.

Comment: "Do I have to purchase an OS as well, or are the items listed all I need to get a computer?" - You don't have to purchase the OS.  You do have to install an OS.  Linux is a free operating system.

Comment: If you mean is the operating pre-installed on the hard drive when you buy components as you are, then no, it's not (unless it's part of a kit maybe)

Comment: Welcome to superuser: If your question has been answered in comments and you wish to accept it you can answer it yourself and accept it giving credit to the person who answered it within the answer... say by @Ramhound ... if he will not answer it in answer format himself after being asked. As for the answer hardware (ssd, hdd,) are not sold with an os installed you will have to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Operating Systems are not preinstalled on hard drives, you need to get an OS and install it on the SSD or in the HDD.

You can buy *Microsoft Windows* or you can download on another system a free OS like a *Linux-flavored distribution* (Ubuntu, Fedora, Mint...etc) or a *BSD descendant* as OpenBSD or NetBSD.